# Add app to Safari share button

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-safari, share, safari-extension

App should be automatically added to Safari share and on tapping Safari share button app shows on it like Facebook or Twitter. How can I implement this functionality?

For further reference I have added a image below.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000018/register-app-to-open-from-safaris-share-or-open-in-dialog-not-working

Comment: @b.zdybowicz Thanx for replay but i have seen this link but its not according to my requirement. can you please suggest something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the share extension feature provided in IOS8.[apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/)